Edit layout in Excel, make 3 highest a color for 3 categories
I have a table with 2 columns, Vehicle and KM. In the vehicle column you select between 3 vehicles, bike, car, motorcycle. In the KM you say how much you drove with that vehicle. I now need to make the 3 rows with the highest KM red for each vehicle, so if someone drives all then there should be 9 rows red. Because there are 3 vehicles to choose from and the 3 highest get marked, the table does not have to be sorted, just that. (Image is in dutch).

If you apply this formula in conditional formatting, where the result is TRUE set the color to the required.
Applied range $D$20:$D$35
The formula in E20:
=LET(filt,FILTER(D$20:D$35,C$20:C$35=C20),
dat,CHOOSECOLS(filt,2),
three,LARGE(filt,SEQUENCE(3)),
IF(OR(D20=three),TRUE,FALSE))


